# Typescript type with multiple conditions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

### What I have

```
interface Tenant {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Server {
  id: number;
  location: string;
  ip: string;
}

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  tenant: number | Tenant;
  server: number | Server;
}
```

### What I want

Properties `tenant` and `server` could be "populated" but by default, they are not. I want to be able to define the type and specify which properties are populated, like this:

```js
const user: User; // both tenant and server are number
const user2: User<{ tenant: Tenant }>; // tenant is populated, server - not
const user3: User<{ tenant: Tenant; server: Server }>; // both props are populated
```

### What did I try

```
interface UserPopulate {
  tenant: Tenant | number;
  server: Server | number;
}

interface DefaultUserPopulate {
  tenant: number;
  server: number;
}

export interface User2<Populate extends UserPopulate = DefaultUserPopulate>{
  id: number;
  name: string;
  tenant: Populate['tenant'];
  server: Populate['server'];
}

const user: User<{ tenant: number }>;
```

But Typescript requires me to define both `tenant` and `server` (`User<{ tenant: number; server: number }>` or nothing (`User`), but I want to be able to override only one "populate"

Comment: So, something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N9nP9m) then?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant `const { a, b } = obj;` destructing feature, not a destructor, but thanks for the comment, will change the question

Comment: @ArūnasSmaliukas - Ah! It's "destructuring" (extracting from a structure). (I'm not seeing how that relates, but it's not important, the title's been changed anyway. :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is conditional types:

```
interface User<T = {}> {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  tenant: T extends {tenant: Tenant} ? Tenant : number;
  server: T extends {server: Server} ? Server : number;
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoRHcyDeAoZZYAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuAiuaicgZzClAHMmAvnjyhIsRCgDK0AG7RczEuSp1GzADYB7BHDDBNITtz5NCwAA5GeIfniEjw0eEmQBVDtAA8qZAF5cAgB8CmZkFDT0UKYsbFYmzJCY4OQ+EAAeicQcuIlYYCkYeQLIAPxohdjKEWqEHlByUCnI6ZnZOHUN5NL10MVl3Q3IVapRdsLqEGDIlHXk7ozIAPSLyLSaYAAWyLnYWMTIHfJwUCgqkXgTUzPQAExzdZ442xX55UlTQQxLKztTwNnmTTmSjqXQQYgAGgOsnkAFoKOsLpNpnUAMz3LxPX4Fd5fQ6NZADeSfb6rdZbcxQIHZY4oQHA0GQYhAA)

But a better approach would be to simplify `T` as the object type is not carrying any useful information, so a simple string union would do.

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoRHcyDeAoZZYAEwC5kQBXAWwCNoBuAiuaicgZzClAHMmAvnjyhIsRCgDK0AG7RczEuSp1GzADYB7BHDDBNITtz5NCwAA5GeIfniEjw0eEmQBVDtAA8qZBAAekCDEHMgARIFYYKHIAD5hHlByUNFxocQQ8JTqUcgAvGHpmdmhAHwKZmQUNPRQpixsVibMEeDk4RiR0f6BwWjIAPxoHdjK1WqECUltk9BdARi9PoPSifKjqrV2wuoQYMiUCeTujMgA9KfItJpgABbILXtYxMgzUMhwUCgqNXg7ewfQABMRwSnnamHApQYZwuDyIIXMmnMWV0EGIABoXrJ5ABaCjXX67fYJADMIK84M6sXi2OSJWh50u1zu5igSJCHxQiOR6lRxDwQA)

```
interface User<T extends "tenant" | "server" | "default" = "default"> {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  tenant: "tenant" extends T ? Tenant : number;
  server: "server" extends T ? Server : number;
}

let user: User; // both tenant and server are number
let user2: User<"tenant">; // tenant is populated, server - not
let user3: User<"tenant" | "server">; // both props are populated
```

Comment: Thanks for both solutions! However first is more flexible, as `Tenant` and `Server` could be optionally populated also `const user: User<{ tenant: Tenant<{foo: Foo}> }>` in case it will be needed.

Comment: In that case, I'd  change my conditionals slightly like this:

```
  tenant: T extends {tenant: infer MyTenant} ? MyTenant : number;

```

Comment: Nice answer! Just FYI, you can tell the playground to show the types using a special comment, [here's an example](https://tsplay.dev/WPp9EW). (And you can get short links for use in comments via https://tsplay.dev. [Best not to use them in answers, but they're good for comments.])